# Download file & get percent complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I Detect how many bytes are downloaded from a large image say 2-4 MB? i.e. to inform the user by the percent of downloaded image?

Comment: How do you plan on using this information? I would say that 2-4 MB would load in a few seconds on most peoples networks today.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII i suggest you visit east of europe. greetings from Turkey

Comment: Please edit your question and show some more of your work.  What have you tried?  What errors have you seen? Show some code samples. Otherwise this question may be closed because it is low quality.

Comment: will on slow networks its differ

Comment: @Gray as i search there is no api for that , but i just want ask if there is workaround !

Answer (score 0):

For anything that normally takes less than 15-30 seconds, a throbber or fake progress indicator is usually good enough to show something is going on.

If you are planning on tracking a bigger download, you may try to download using a custom build ajax downloader and get progress info when XMLHTTPRequest.readystate == 3.

See http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php  for a start on building the custom ajax downloader.

Alternatively, have the server keep track of your ajax download and spawn a separate ajax call to ping for status. This is a bit tricky, and I'm sorry I don't have an example for you.

And no, there's no way to track a download progress on a normal  tag.